# Object Detection Tensorflow 2.6- How to save all checkpoints and run eval for all checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Object Detection Tensorflow 2.6 -

while training the model, only last 7 checkpoints are getting saved. The older ones are overwritten. How to save all checkpoints
and how to run eval model for all these checkpoints.only last checkpoint value is taken for evaluation

I tried to run train and eval at same time, got Out of Memory error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The tf.train.Saver() constructor takes an optional argument called max_to_keep, which defaults to keeping the 5 most recent checkpoints of your model. To save more models, simply specify a value for that argument:

To keep all checkpoints, pass the argument **max_to_keep=None** to the saver constructor.

**max_to_keep** - indicates the maximum number of recent checkpoint files to keep. As new files are created, older files are deleted. If None or 0, no checkpoints are deleted from the filesystem but only the last one is kept in the checkpoint file. Defaults to 5 (that is, the 5 most recent checkpoint files are kept.)

**keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours** - In addition to keeping the most recent max_to_keep checkpoint files, you might want to keep one checkpoint file for every N hours of training. This can be useful if you want to later analyze how a model progressed during a long training session. For example, passing keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=2 ensures that you keep one checkpoint file for every 2 hours of training. The default value of 10,000 hours effectively disables the feature.

Comment: Hi Mohan ,Thank You.  where will i find the tf.train.Saver() constructor in TF2 Object Detection Model

Comment: You can modify (hardcoding in your fork or opening a pull request and adding the options to protos) the arguments passed to tf.train.Saver in:

[object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py#L376-L377)

You will probably want to set:

max_to_keep: Maximum number of recent checkpoints to keep. Defaults to 5.
keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours: How often to keep checkpoints. Defaults to 10,000 hours. These links can help you, https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4636  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8930